# Sqlite query not returning 0 value

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have this query to fetch some ids from my sqlite DB...

```
Select a.Id3,a.Id4,a.Id5 from OfflineTable a
left JOIN Smatee s3 on s3.id = a.Id3 
left JOIN Smatee s4 on s4.id = a.Id4 left JOIN Smatee s5 on s5.id = a.Id5 where a.Id = '123'
```

When I hit this query in DBBrowser for SQLite, it returnds me records like this

| Id3 | Id4 | Id5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1456 | 0 | 2463 |

But when I run this query in my code, it gives me the records like so...

```
{
 Id3 = 1456;
 Id4 =  "";
 Id5 = 2463;
}
```

i.e.,instead of returning the value 0 for `Id4`, it returns `""`. Why is this happening..?

Also this is how I execute this sqlite query in my code

In my `ViewCOntroller`...

`let arrDetails = sharedInstance.getSpecificElementsFromOfflineTable(self.rowID)`

And in another class called `SQLHelper.swift` ,

`let sharedInstance = SQLHelper()`

```
        func getSpecificElementsFromOfflineTable(_ rowId: Int) -> NSMutableArray {
            let items: NSMutableArray = []
            sharedInstance.database!.open()

            let rs: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("Select a.Id3,a.Id4,a.Id5 from OfflineTable a left JOIN Smatee s3 on s3.id = a.Id3 left JOIN Smatee s4 on s4.id = a.Id4 left JOIN Smatee s5 on s5.id = a.Id5 where a.Id = ?", withArgumentsIn: [rowId])
           
            
            if(rs != nil)
            {
                while rs.next() {
                let dic = NSMutableDictionary()

             
                dic.setObject("\(rs.string(forColumn: "Id3") ?? "")", forKey: "Id3" as NSCopying)
                dic.setObject("\(rs.string(forColumn: "Id4") ?? "")", forKey: "Id4" as NSCopying)
                dic.setObject("\(rs.string(forColumn: "Id5") ?? "")", forKey: "Id5" as NSCopying)
                
                items.add(dic)
            }
        }
        sharedInstance.database!.close()
        return items
    }
```

Comment: and what happens if the default for id4 is 0 instead of ""?

Comment: When I execute the query in my code, I get the value for id4 as `""` @Russell. ....while it should have returned `0`

Comment: if you are expecting numbers to be returned, shouldn't you be using `int(forColumn columnName: String)` ? Then your default for no data can be zero and not ""

Comment: But in some cases some column might have `null` values in which case it should  correctly return `""`. So if I give `int(forColumn columnName: String)`, then even those columns which doesn't have any value will return a 0 which will be incorrect.

Comment: This is confusing, what type is Id4 in the table and does it contain a value or not in this case?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It does contain the value of 0. In case of not having a value, the column value will be `null`

Comment: So it's an integer that you treat as a string, maybe the issue is with that framework you are using or maybe it got something to do with you using all those old objective-c types instead of native swift types.